# Unable to remove element and children in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a block of data holding user information, so the tree of data looks something like:

```
app
  -Jweljralsdjfo49
    username: "Fred"
    age: 25
    shoesize: 16
```

I'm trying to do:

```
var ref = new Firebase(my_app_path + stored_user_id);
ref.remove();
```

I've also tried;

```
var ref = new Firebase(my_app_path);
var child = ref.child(stored_user_id);
child.remove();
```

Neither one works, in that the data is always still there.

The documentation for remove() states: "Remove the data at this Firebase location. Any data at child locations will also be deleted.", so I expect it to all to be gone.

I've tried adding a callback, and in each case the callback gets called with `null` (indicating success, quoting the docs: "The callback will be passed an Error object on failure, else null.").

What am I doing wrong?  Is it because I'm using the user ID?  I'm not using any security rules at the moment, but once I do, for security restrictions, I don't want non-users to be able to delete user content.

THANKS!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDIT: Found the problem.

I'm using EmberFire, which works fine; but the `EmberFire.Object` which keeps track of the object has to be destroy()'d, and then I had to do:

```
Ember.run.later(function() {
  var ref = new Firebase(my_app_path + stored_user_id);
  ref.remove();
}, 1);
```

In order for the object to be officially gone, and for Ember/EmberFire to release its grip on the data.

Comment: Can you add a console.log(ref.toString()) before calling .remove() and make sure the URL is what you expect? (You could paste it into your browser and see if the correct data shows up in Forge).

Comment: Seems like OP found the solution himself.

Answer (score 0):

you can probe adding `$` to remove.
Example:

```
var ref = new Firebase(my_app_path + stored_user_id);
ref.$remove();
```

work for me.