# How can I delete data from firebase thru web app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's my JavaScript code.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('User');
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

  var description = snap.child("description").val();
  var title = snap.child("title").val();
  var article = snap.child("article").val();

  $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + title + "</td><td>" + description + "</td><td>" + article + "</td><td><button>Remove</td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: I've not worked with firebase but here's a quick [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZqXcoqC95E) I found on how to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: possible duplicate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537720/how-to-delete-remove-nodes-on-firebase

Comment: Please don't name non-root references `rootRef`, I've seen this trip up too many developers. In your case here, it is more appropriate to call it `userRef` (or `userRootRef` if you want it to be the root of the `'User'` tree), which you can also initialize using `var userRef = firebase.database().ref('User');`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to delete data is to call remove() on a reference to the location of that data. So in your case, you'd need to have a function to delete the data, passing in the child key then calling the function when the remove button is clicked.

```
function deleteData(dataKey) {
  firebase.database().ref('User/' + dataKey).remove()
}
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('User');
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

  var description = snap.child("description").val();
  var title = snap.child("title").val();
  var article = snap.child("article").val();

  $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + title + "</td><td>" + description + "</td><td>" + article + "</td><td><button onclick='deleteData(" + snap.key()  + ")'>Remove</td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: thanks man! but when i try to run it i get an error saying snap.key is not a function

Comment: It works but sometime it showed an error saying SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list it point out  the html file

Comment: <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Article</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_body">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js">
</script>
<script>